# angular and typescript compatible versions for @syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I am using the following versions in my package.json
"@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons": "^17.1.50",
"typescript": "^2.9.2",
"@angular/cli": "^6.0.0-rc.5",

When building the project without prod tag ng build, it appears to be successful.

But when I try to optimize and run the ng build --prod, it throws me error

ERROR in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons.es5.js
Module build failed: Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
    at getJSDocTags (C:\workspace\newui\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13197:22).

I tried to downgrade the "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons": "^16.1.37" and ng build --prod is working fine but it is not compatible with my @syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids package.

Can someone suggest how to resolve the build error for version 17.1.50

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your reported issue and we suspect that typescript version “^2.9.2” referred in your package.json file caused this issue. So, we suggest you change the typescript version in 3.x (e.g. "typescript": "~3.4.3") and the "@angular-devkit/build-angular" version to "0.10.3” in package.json file to resolve this issue.

For your convenience, we have prepared a sample and same can be downloaded from below link, 
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/240314/ze/my-app-1208801535

Could you please check the above sample and get back to us if you need any further assistance on this?

Regards,

Vinoth Kumar S